# Create rectangle shape drawable with two side curved corner in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I create a shape drawable resource xml file for a create a background with two side curved corner. 

Here I post my code of Shape drawable.  But it not give me right result. It give me 4 side curved image.
So I just wanted to know how to create 2 side curved shape image.

Thanks

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#0579CD" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="8dp"
    android:left="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:top="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the miner value to non-curve corner field.
in your case:

```
<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
```

And one thing more. the preview are not show in graphical layout. You should try to see in device.

 I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" 
/>
```

you are giving all side radius , so it is giving you the right result. you have to give only two options like:

```
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" 

/>
```

or any other possible condition.